# How to programmatically determine whether a node is a og group type node?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

Drupal 7, OG

How to programmatically determine whether a node is an og group type node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, much faster/easier/supposed-to-be-done-this-way-er: [og_is_group_type()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--og--og.module/function/og_is_group_type/7)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this using [`og_get_group_ids()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--og--og.module/function/og_get_group_ids/7) :

```
og_get_group_ids('node', array($nid));
```

If the result is not empty then the node is an og group type node.

Comment: og_get_group($entity_type, $etid, $create = FALSE, $states = array(OG_STATE_ACTIVE), $reset = FALSE)   also does it.  http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--og--og.module/function/og_get_group/7

Comment: Any idea how to do this in OG 7.x-2.x? It uses the entity API and did away with a bunch of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

For the 7.x-2.x branch you can use:

```
og_is_group('node', $node)
```